# JAVA/JSON: Parsing multiple object data

Tags: java, json

I have an existing 200MB JSON file: yelp_training_set_review.json`.

### Data format:

```
{"votes": "1", "funny": "2", "useful": "3"} {"votes ":" 4 "," funny ":" 5 "," useful ":" 6 "} {" votes ":" 7 "," funny ":" 8 "," useful ":" 9 "}......
```

Note that there is no comma  between two objects {}, I can only parse the first object(one {}) using the following code.

How to get the size of objects in the file, or how to parse all objects?

### Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(new FileReader(
            new File("C:\\yelp_training_set_review.json"))));

             for (int i = 0; i < jsonobject.length(); i++) {
        int k = jsonobject.length();
        System.out.println(jsonobject.getString("votes "));
        System.out.println(jsonobject.getString("funny "));
        System.out.println(jsonobject.getString("useful "));

         }
}
```

Comment: Get the string, add in commas between objects, read with your code.

Comment: Or - if you don't want to read 200MB in one string - start a buffered file reader, add the characters one by one into a initially empty string and whenever you find '}' character create a JSONObject from this string, read the contents and start with a new empty string again until you have reached the end of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem. Using,

```
while(temp!=null){          
            teststring=temp;
             temp=br.readLine();
            System.out.println(teststring);             

        JSONTokener jsonParser = new JSONTokener(teststring);  
        JSONObject  jsonobject=new JSONObject(jsonParser);      

        JSONObject VotejsonObject = jsonobject.getJSONObject("votes");                  
        System.out.println(VotejsonObject.getInt("funny")); 
        System.out.println(VotejsonObject.getInt("useful")); 
        System.out.println(VotejsonObject.getInt("cool"));       
        System.out.println(jsonobject.getString("user_id"));
        System.out.println(jsonobject.getString("review_id"));
        System.out.println(jsonobject.getInt("stars"));
        System.out.println(jsonobject.getString("date"));
        System.out.println(jsonobject.getString("text"));
        System.out.println(jsonobject.getString("type"));
        System.out.println(jsonobject.getString("business_id"));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the string is not JSON, as Justin Jasmman said, add the commas. You can read about JSON format on [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) or [here](http://www.json.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I modified the content of your JSON string as it was not a valid JSON.
You can validate your JSON string [**here**](http://jsonlint.com/).

### Modified JSON:

```
{
    "category": "Voting",
    "votes": [
        {
            "funny": 2,
            "useful": 3,
            "total": 5
        },
        {
            "funny": 5,
            "useful": 5,
            "total": 10
        },

        {
            "funny": 12,
            "useful": 15,
            "total": 27
        }
    ]
}
```

### Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  JSONObject myJsonObject = new JSONObject(
    new JSONTokener(
       new FileReader(
        new File(
                    "D:\\yelp_training_set_review.json"))));
  JSONArray myJsonArray = (JSONArray) myJsonObject.get("votes");
  for (int i = 0, size = myJsonArray.length(); i < size; i++) {
    JSONObject myJObject = myJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    System.out.println(myJObject.toString());
  }
}
```

### Output:

```
{"total":5,"funny":2,"useful":3}
{"total":10,"funny":5,"useful":5}
{"total":27,"funny":12,"useful":15}
```

Hope that helps.